# How to stop NetBeans from Suggesting Variable Names?

Tags: netbeans

I love NetBeans and its auto-completion features. However, I wish the IDE stops suggesting variable names. For example, when I type "bool myVar" and a space, I ended up with "bool myVarB". The extra "B" suffix drives me nut. How can I turn off this behavior? I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to Options and under Editor there is a tab for Code Completion.  Uncheck auto pop up completion window.

If you need the completion window use Ctrl+space to bring it up.

Comment: Not sure he has a problem with the popup.

Comment: @Mark: Thanks for the tip. However, that disable too much. For example, it disabled suggesting of types (bool, String). As you said, Ctrl+Space will bring it up, but that key combo is currently used by Butler (a program launcher). I know that I can configure the hot keys, but I have reasons not to. So for now, I'm going to enable that pop-up and learn to live with it.